# Springboot 2.0.5 and MongoDB TimeSeries

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, time-series

I have a project with 16 micro-services using Springboot 2.0.5. One of the service that calculates OHLCV of a very large trade data stored in Mongo collection.

MongoDB 6.0 has introduced timeseries functionalities that can make our life easier. But going through Mongo and Spring docs, I realized that I'll need to upgrade my Springboot version to 2.7.x, because I am currently using **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb**, which doesn't have TimeSeries support.

I have also tried to migrate entire project to 2.7.4, removing Netflix Zuul, which is literally a backbone of entire architecture, but it was way too much of change. So I have decided to roll back to what was and is working fine. And it doesn't feel logical to migrate such large code base for just one feature support.

Is there any other way we can use timeseries functionality in Mongo (or other DB) which supports Springboot 2.0.5 ? The data we are talking is millions of document....

Comment: well, maybe you can override spring mongodb starter dependency and then use mongodb version 5.0 or higher. https://dzone.com/articles/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Comment: That's a great article, very close to something I was looking for. But reading through that, I realized that there are other 8 micro-services using mongoDB (spring drivers), which may be a concern. I guess, only solution is to use some TSDB like influx for one specific service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming to this hoping for an easy answer, there isn't (at least  I couldn't find it)

The way I solved is to NOT use any dependecy hack to support latest MongoDB drivers in an old Spring boot version.

Rather, I used PostGres with TimeScaleDB extension which supports OHLCV out of the box with minimum code. Also, is way too faster, and way more easy then to work around the dependency version issues.